# Predicate Logic - Formula

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic

Assume it is given $2$ predicates as below:

$A(x):$ $x$ is a horse;

$B(x,y):$ $x$ is a tail of $y$.

Then, translate the following sentence into predicate logic formula:
"$w$ is a tail of horse" - where $w$ is arbitrary variable

My ideas: I am struggling on which variable out of $w$ and horse, we should pick up as existential, and universal? Would appreciate to know your ideas.

Update: Is the formula for above sentence expressed as $\forall(y)(A(y) \Rightarrow B(w,y))$?

Comment: The $w$ doesn't get a quantifier, it's just a constant in the statement.

Comment: But I have been told that $w$ is regarded as a variable, meaning we should use either existential to universal quantifier for it.

Comment: A "constant" in first order logic is really just a variable being used to denote a specific object in the universe it is taken from.

Comment: I agree with @coffeemath , in the statement the variable $w$ is not quantified

Comment: What is $H$ in your formula?

Comment: I see, so there is not any way to come up with formula using variable $w$ as quantifier? What about then, variable for horse? I think this is formula I obtained using variable $y$ for horse, but unsure on that: $\forall(y)(A(y) \Rightarrow B(w,y))$.


Note: Sorry for confusion in my initial comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the instructions, $w$ is supposed to be a free variable that remains unquantified. It acts as a placeholder to insert arbitrary names for, like in the definitions of the two predicates you gave, where $x$ and $y$ are not bound either.

Your proposal is incorrect. Your formula expresses "$w$ is the tail of *every* horse". But that's not the meaning of "a tail's horse". "horse's tail" means "*a* horse's tail" -- that particular tail is the tail of one horse, not all the horses in the world -- so the horse variable will be existentially, not universally quantified.
Also, as explained in the answer to your [other post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3840643/predicate-logic-and-inference), "a horse's tail" means that $w$ is the tail of $y$ *and* $y$ is a horse -- so you need conjunction, not implication. As a rule of thumb, existential quantifiers go with conjunction and universal quantifiers go with implication.

Can you figure out the correct solution given these hints?

Comment: Well, I do not agree that existential quantifier will be used. In my opinion, correct formula should be the following:
$\forall(y)(A(y) \Rightarrow B(w,y))$

Comment: @rentbuyer? Why do you think so?

Comment: Can you provide formula with existential quantifier? I think my formula works pretty normal.

Comment: Dear, I have already done that)

Comment: Besides that, do you think my formula has any problems?

Comment: Okay man, I will try not to do that next time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113427/discussion-between-rentbuyer-and-lemontree).

Comment: I updated my post, with an explanation of why your proposal does not work.

Comment: Could you provide formula? I could not figure out @lemontree

Comment: I pretty much already gave you the solution -- use an existential instead of a universal quantifier and conjunction instead of implication -- I'm sure you can figure out the rest of on your own.

Comment: Okay, let me see it: Is it $\exists(y)(A(y) \wedge B(w,y))$? If yes, then just put upvote!

Comment: That's correct.